# How can I set a field property to readonly based on a variables value in html

Tags: html, variables, readonly

In a form on a website the values for name and password are automatic for Users but can be edited for Admins. The $role variable holds the value to be checked

What is the correct way to check the value of $role and set the 'readonly' attribute based on that.

```
<td class=input>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="$username" size="20" maxlength="30" class="input" readonly >
</td>
```

Comment: Plus, there are no variables or an if statement in HTML. So add whatever programming language you are using.

Comment: Sorry, i tried addign the code but it would not allow it whether in blockcode or html indented even a simple 3 lines

Comment: Name: input type="text" id="username" readonly
Password: input type="text" id="username" readonly

Comment: if="$role='User'" <input type="text" id="username" readonly> else <input type="text" id="username"

Comment: Sorry this is about as much as I can add here witout something telling me it is not allowed the way I am doing it  The html does display very much like that.  The "Question of" If$role=user does not display like that but I assure you in general it is taken from a file edit.html.  The question applies .  In html how can I test the value of a variable before setting a text field to readonly?  If correctly shown I can modify it as needed. Thanks

Comment: <td class=input><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="$username" size="20" maxlength="30" class="input" readonly ></td>

Comment: @questorfla that's more like it ;) Now, what programming language are you using? PHP? C#? Or is this purely JavaScript?

Comment: It may be javascript but the file name is "edit.html".  Sorry if I asked incorrectly.  Site 'is' mostly PHP but does call a few .JS modules.  The problem is I need that line and another to be selective so it is read-only if $role=User but editable if $role=Admin